# setTimeout behaves differently dependant on function parameter passed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple throttle for a search field, to make sure that not every keypress is sent as a query, it waits 300ms after a keypress before submitting. If another keypress is detected before the 300ms is up, the clock resets.

I have it setup in Vue as below:

```
<input v-model="search_string" placeholder="Search..." type="text" @keyup="searchThrottle();">

runSearch (type) {
    do something....
}

searchThrottle () {
    if (window.ajaxtimeout) clearTimeout(window.ajaxtimeout)

    window.ajaxtimeout = setTimeout(this.runSearch, 300)
},
```

There is a different in the way it works dependant on this line: `window.ajaxtimeout = setTimeout(this.runSearch, 300)`

for example, if I pass through a parameter so the line is `window.ajaxtimeout = setTimeout(this.runSearch('autocomplete'), 300)` the search is run for each keypress, ignoring the timeout.

Why is the functionality different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you palce `this.runSearch('autocomplete')` in your `setTimeout`, the `runSearch` function will be executed immediately, and not after the expected  `300ms`.

So you could add the parameter for your `runSearch` function to the `setTimeout` initialization:

```
setTimeout(this.runSearch, 300, 'autocomplete');
```

Or you could use a closure, but need to store `this` before:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function {
    self.runSearch('autocomplete');
}, 300);
```

And as @JaromandaX mentioned in comments, you could do the same thing a bit shorter with ECMAScript 6:

```
setTimeout(() => this.runSearch('autocomplete'), 300);
```

---

There is another way, using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a function reference, that passes `this` and additional parameters to the `runSearch` function. This works well too, but this feels a bit *hacky* to me. I personally don't like that apraoch, because of maintenance and readability. But to have a most complete answer, I've added that example too (*first post was from @BrotherWoodrow about this*):

```
setTimeout(this.runSearch.bind(this, 'autocomplete'), 300);
```

---

[More information about setTimeout on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: modern javascript you can also `setTimeout(() =>this.runSearch('autocomplete'), 300);`

Comment: Correct. I hope it is okay that I added this to my answer. @JaromandaX

Answer (score 2):

> setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)

The params of setTimeout function are not supported in IE9 and earlier. To solve this issue you can use currying.

```
var that = this;
    myCustomSearch(type){
        return function(){
        that.runSearch(type)
        }
    }


    setTimeout(this.myCustomSearch('autocomplete'), 300)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because setTimeout needs a function *reference*. If you put `this.runSearch()` it will get executed immediately. To create a function reference and pass parameters, use `bind`:

```
window.ajaxtimeout = setTimeout(this.runSearch.bind(this, 'autocomplete'), 300)
```

If you use Lodash, it has a [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle) function for this very purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In the first variation, you're telling the browser to wait 300ms and then call `this.runSearch()`.

In the second variation, the one where you're passing parameters into the function, you're telling the browser to run `this.runSearch('autocomplete')` so it does.

If you want to pass parameters into the `this.runSearch` function while still having the timer work, you can to wrap it in a function:

```
function runDelayedSearch(){
  this.runSearch('autocomplete');
}
window.ajaxtimeout = setTimeout(runDelayedSearch, 300)
```

You can do this more concisely in ES6 with:

`window.ajaxtimeout = setTimeout(() => runSearch('autocomplete'), 300)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use bind function like:

```
setTimeout(this.runSearch.bind(this, 'autocomplete'), 300)
```

This won't execute the function on instantiation